# Avoiding SQL injection using a non parameterised query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Im aware of how parameterised queries work, and ive used them in every non hardcoded query I've written so far, however when writing a function to create a dynamic query (for testing purposes) it made me question whether it would actually be safe to use "as is"

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE";

string fullstring = "The quick brown fox jumped over";
string[] words = fullstring.Split(' ');

foreach (string item in words)
{
    sql = sql + " Column LIKE '%" + item + "%' AND";
}

sql = sql.Remove(sql.Length - 3);
```

If I were to turn this into a query, the result would be

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE '%the%' AND Column LIKE '%quick%' AND Column LIKE '%brown%' AND Column LIKE '%fox%' AND Column LIKE '%jumped%' AND Column LIKE '%over%'
```

Now i'm still pretty sure that this is still open to injection attacks due to the lack of parameters, however i'm unsure how due to the delimiter being a space character making things like `SELECT * FROM TABLE` or `DROP TABLE` unable to be written in the string as each would be split into their own strings ie. `SELECT`,`*`,`FROM`and `TABLE`

Can anyone enlighten me further?

(Note, not planning on using this as an alternative to proper parameters, just trying to understand)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select"name"from"sys"."columns"
```

Is an example of a query I can write that SQL Server will process and that contains no spaces.

So, just say no.

---

Here's another example showing another way of bypassing "no spaces" and in an "injected" form:

```
select name from sys.columns where name like '%a'union/**/all/**/select/**/name/**/from/**/sys.objects
```

Comment: Fantastic example of what i was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: Also, splitting a string on `' '` does not remove tabs nor does it removes line breaks, so...

Comment: And you can also just use `/**/` to separate tokens also

Comment: Or add the following to the end of the sentence: `%';DROP TABLE table;--` (note that the spaces are actually tabs, and they won't be filtered out by your split.

Answer (score 1):

If the string was formated like that:

```
string fullstring = "DROP\tTABLE\tTableName";
```

you would still have a problem with injection...
Just a simple example.